# PayPal IPN Listener keeps 'Retrying' HTTP Response 500

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal-ipn

My IPN Listener has been working fine for the last 6 months. This last week though, all transactions are 'Retrying' and causing a HTTP 500 Response. I haven't changed any code in the IPN Listener and I haven't changed any settings in PayPal. I have rang PayPal and they say it's not a problem their end. My hosting company 1&1 Ionos have pretty much no idea what I'm talking about. My IPN Listener code is below. My site uses Asp.Net/VB.Net..

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web.Util
Imports System.Data.Common

Partial Class IPNListener
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Post back to either sandbox or live
        'Dim strURL As String = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
        Dim strURL As String = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(strURL), HttpWebRequest)

        'Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST"
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        req.Proxy = New WebProxy("ntproxyus.lxa.perfora.net", 3128)

        Dim Param() As Byte = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength)
        Dim strRequest As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Param)
        strRequest = strRequest + "&cmd=_notify-validate"
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length

        'Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        Dim streamOut As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII)
        streamOut.Write(strRequest)
        streamOut.Close()
        Dim streamIn As StreamReader = New StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        Dim strResponse As String = streamIn.ReadToEnd()
        streamIn.Close()

        Dim qscoll As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(strRequest)

        'Insert the paypal response
        Dim order As New orders
        order.InsertPaypalResponse(qscoll("txn_id"), qscoll("custom"), strRequest)

        If strResponse = "VERIFIED" Then
              order.UpdateOrderFromPaypal(qscoll("custom"), qscoll("txn_id"), qscoll("payment_status"))
        ElseIf strResponse = "INVALID" Then
            'log for manual investigation
            order.UpdateOrderFromPaypal(qscoll("custom"), qscoll("txn_id"), qscoll("payment_status"))
        Else
            'Response wasn't VERIFIED or INVALID, log for manual investigation
            order.UpdateOrderFromPaypal(qscoll("custom"), qscoll("txn_id"), qscoll("payment_status"))
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IPN listener likely is having problems connecting to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr in order to validate the IPNs it receives, and so is refusing to process the IPN and returning an HTTP 500, causing PayPal to retry its delivery repeatedly.

For your listener to be able to connect to PayPal and validate IPNs, you need to ensure you have an updated Certificate Authority bundle / list that is able to verify the issuer of the PayPal servers' current, cryptographically secure SSL certificates.

While you are at it, update your IPN listener to use `ipnpb.paypal.com` rather than www.paypal.com See the current documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know much about this stuff but as you suggested, I have changed the strURL in the above code to include ipnpb.paypal.com rather than www.paypal.com but still no luck. My hosting is with 1&1 ionos and I bought an SSL certificate though them. When you say i need to update my Certificate Authority Bundle, is that something I can do or is it up to the hosting company? I don't know where to start with that. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have just re-issued my 1&1 SSL certificate but still no luck.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your site's certificate. The certificate in question is the one used by PayPal's servers. Your IPN listener will not able to connect to PayPal's servers if it is not able to verify the issuer of the certificate they are using. For this to happen the software you are using to connect to PayPal via HTTPS needs to trust the certificate authority that trusts the issuer that signed the certificate that PayPal's servers are using. Thus, you need to make changes in Asp.Net/VB.Net or on the webserver to trust the relevant certificate authority.

Comment: Ah I understand now. However, I'm quite limited with 1&1 with what I can do. Their customer service doesn't understand what I'm talking about either. Do you have any idea what changes I need to make in VB.Net to be able to trust this certificate? Apologies for my lack of knowledge on all this and thanks again.